# Problemas con la herencia en subclases

Tags: python, python-3.x, herencia, diseño-de-clases

Estoy teniendo problemas para la herencia de ciertos métodos o atributos en subclases de una clase determinada. El problema surge a la hora de imprimir con el `print` para comprobar si todo funciona correctamente. Pero parece ser que no se está heredando variables definidas en la superclase. En este ejemplo en concreto cuando intento imprimir algún método que se va a sobrescribir me devuelve un error de que no están definidas algunas variables.

Esta seria mi super clase:

```
class Secuencia:
def __init__(self, secuencia):
    self.__secuencia = secuencia 
    longitud = len(secuencia) 
def __str__(self):
    cadena =  'La secuencia es: {0}\n'.format(self.__secuencia)
    cadena = cadena + 'La longitud de la secuencia es de: {0}\n'.format(len(self.__secuencia))
    return cadena

def get_secuencia(self):
    return self.__secuencia
def frecuencia_base(self):
    pass
```

Una de mis subclases seria esta:

```
class DNA(Secuencia):
    bases = {'A','T', 'C','G'}  
    bases_complementarias = {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'C':'G','G':'C'}
def __init__(self, secuencia):
    super().__init__(secuencia) #hereda "secuencia" de la superclase Secuencia por qué no puedo ponerla en el __str__ de DNA? o en el return del metodo frecuencia_base
    self.__longitud = len(secuencia)
    bases = {'A','T','C','G'}
    secuencia_set = set(secuencia)
    if secuencia_set <= bases: #comprobacion de que es de DNA
        print('Ha introducido una secuencia de DNA', secuencia, 'de longitud', len(secuencia))
    else: #En caso contrario generamos un mensaje de error y generamos un tipo de error nuevo.
        print('Secuencia de DNA INCORRECTA')
        raise NameError('errorSecuencia') #tipo de error generado.  

def frecuencia_base(self):
    A = 0
    T = 0
    C = 0
    G = 0
    for base in secuencia:
        if base == 'A':
            A += 1
        elif base == 'T':
            T += 1
        elif base == 'C':
            C +=1
        elif base == 'G':
            G +=1  
        return El contenido de bases es:\n  A: {}\n  T:{}\n  C: {}\n  G: {}'.format(A, T, C, G)

def __str__(self):
    contenido = 'El contenido de bases es:\n  A: {}\n  T:{}\n  C: {}\n  G: {}'.format(A, T, C, G)
    return contenido
```

A la hora de hacer el .frecuencia_base(). Me sale un error de que secuencia no está definido pero se supone que ha sido heredado de la superclase no? O es que no tengo que declarar un nuevo **str** en la subclase para poder imprimir con `print`

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que es  `secuencia`?, porque ahora mismo es tratada como una variable local del método `frecuencia_base` que no está definida¿Es el atrubuto `self.__secuencia`? La variable `secuencia` que pasas al inicializador es local a este, no un atributo de instancia.

Comment: Es la misma secuencia que proviene de la superclase "Secuencia"

Comment: Puede que sea debido a eso, a que no es un atributo de instancia. Lo que intento es trabajar con  la secuencia que aparece en la superclase en las subclases y poder crear metodos en ellas y aplicar la secuencia

Comment: `super` no hace que se herede nada de forma explícita, sirve para pasar la variable `secuencia` al inicializador de la clase padre y llamarlo desde la clase hija.  Los atributos y métodos de la clase padre son heredados por la hija y se llaman igual. Puedes acceder al atributo de instancia `self.__secuencia` del padre en el hijo con ese mismo nombre, igual que haces en la clase padre. Por otro lado, las variables A, T, C, y G no existen en el método `__str__` del hijo, son locales al método `frecuencia_base`.

Comment: De acuerdo, creo haber entendido el problema. Muchas gracias intentaré hacer los cambios necesarios para conseguir que funcione.

Comment: @FJSevilla ¿Eso sería válido como respuesta?